# HTMLCollection.item() function returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angular app I am using plain JS to get the elements by class name
Code:

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName("project-link");
console.log(testElements);
```

this prints as such:

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]
0: a.project-link.ng-binding
1: a.project-link.ng-binding
...
30: a.project-link.ng-binding
length: 32
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

However. if I try printing an item alone, this returns null:

```
console.log(testElements.item(4));
null
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this code, I have also tried the Array.prototype.filter.call function and it doesn't work either.
 Any ideas?

Comment: Itsn't it an array? Shouldn't you be using testElements[]

Comment: It is an array, but I don't understand what you mean by saying I should be using testElements[] . if I console out something like testElements[3] I just get an undefined error

Comment: also, might be worth mentioning that when trying     console.log(testElements.length); this turns out 0

Comment: I come to the same problem as you did, and still no solutions...Do you think it might relate to lifecycle?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this bug by adding my code inside the window load function:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   // your code ....
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because the JS code is loaded before the dom tree in the HTML is built. At this time, the page is still empty, so null is returned.

Use window.onload

```
<script >
    window.onload = function() {
        const testElement=document.getElementsByClassName("project-link").item(0);
        console.log(testElement);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(testElements.item(4));
}, 0);
```

Try this,
It might help~
I don't know why, but it works for me.

Comment: Just for the why, it's because putting 0 delay the set time out to after the rest of the code has been executed